# What exactly is super.onMeasure() and super.onLayout() use for?

Tags: java, android

I recently just created a custom view group to test whether or not you really need to include `super.onMeasure()` or `super.onLayout()` when extending the view or viewgroup and overriding the `onMeasure()` and `onLayout()` method. What I found was that you don't need to include the `super.onMeasure()` or `super.onLayout()` and everything still works fine.

So if that is the case what exactly is `super.onMeasure()` and `super.onLayout()` use for and why should I even call it to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the source code & javadoc. That answers the question whether to call `super` or not in most cases.
Do you want to replace the default behavior or inherit it? Replace = don't call. Inherit = call it.

For example some views may only have to do some work in addition to the default, they can call super & then do their bit.
That said:

- `onLayout` is `abstract` & therefore empty. It's still legal to call `super.onLayout` but there is actually no code that can be executed. So don't bother.
- `onMeasure` is the default of `View` and will `setMeasuredDimension()` based on `getSuggestedMinimumWidth/Height()` which is most of the time not the behavior you want to inherit in a view group because you'll probably want to adjust your measurements based on your children.

The only thing you shouldn't do is call `super.onMeasure()` after your code has set measurements. That would destroy your work.

Comment: That's it. If you someday need to read the height/width of a `View` you will need to wait for the measures to be performed and set, before reading them. I don't think they matter if you don't need them, but if you did need them, you would get problems like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/getwidth-and-getheight-of-view-returns-0) one.